# UITapGestureRecognizer is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a table where a gesturerecognizer should be added to the table-header-label. This is done through following code:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleTableheaderTap:)];
    [headerView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
    singleFingerTap.delegate = self;
```

The selector-method looks like following:

```
- (void)handleTableheaderTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
```

Unfortunately, the recognizer is nil, when the method is called. What do I have to change, so the recognizer is in the handletTableheaderTap not nil anymore?

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly are you determining that "the recognizer is nil when the method is called"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the instance in a controller attribute.
Declare a private property to store it.

Example :

```
@interface MyViewController()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap
@end
```

...

```
self.singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleTableheaderTap:)];
 [headerView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
  singleFingerTap.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Comment for the  -1 ?